# Move to next and subsquent pages when page is idle for 3 seconds on each page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone help me to come with with a script that automatically moves in between page when the page is idle for 3 seconds? Currently with what i have it can only move from one page to the other but i'm having 4 pages which i would want it to affect it all.

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="page1">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page1</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">This is page 1</div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;
    <div data-role="page" id="page2">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">This is page 2</div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp;
    <div data-role="page" id="page3">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 3</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">This is page 3</div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;
    <div data-role="page" id="page4">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 4</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">This is page 4</div>
      <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>

Here's a fiddle to my page
```

http://jsfiddle.net/91wu20fr/

JQUERY

```
$(function () {
  $(document).on("mousemove keypress", function () {
    clearTimeout(goToNextPage);
    goToNextPage = setTimeout(function () {
      location.href = '#page2';
    }, 3000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Note, `div` is not valid child element of `p` element. Removed `p` elements that were parents of `div` element

`html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js">
</script>
<script src="script.js"></script>   
<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">This is page 1</div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">This is page 2</div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page 3</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">This is page 3</div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Page 4</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">This is page 4</div>
    <div data-role="footer">
      <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If `hash` of `location` begins at `#page1` could use `Number()` , `String.prototype.slice()` to increment pages using existing `js` .

Defined `mousemove`, `keypress` event handler as named function , substituted `.one()` for `.on()` to prevent handler being called at each `mousemove` event ; defined `goToNextPage` variable outside of `.one()` handler

js

```
$(function() {
  location.href = "#page1"
  var goToNextPage = null;
  function updatePage(event) {
    console.log(event)
    var currentPage = Number(location.hash.slice(-1));
    // if `currentPage` is less than 4
    if (currentPage !== 4) {
      goToNextPage = setTimeout(function() {
        if ((currentPage + 1) <= 4) {
          // set `location.href` to `#page` + `currentPage` + `1`
          location.href = "#page" + (currentPage + 1);
          console.log(location.hash);
          // reset event handlers
          $(document).one("mousemove keypress", updatePage);
        } 
      }, 3000);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(goToNextPage)
    }
  }
  $(document).one("mousemove keypress", updatePage);
});
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/tunX9CjEqNEZWxoxXU1b?p=preview

Comment: its suppose to wait for some few seconds before trigger the action. can you fiddle it?

Comment: _"Currently with what i have it can only move from one page to the other"_ Yes, does existing `js` at Question navigate from `#page1` to `#page2` ?

Comment: with my js, i get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: goToNextPage is not defined"

Comment: wow thanks it worked, i wanted to ask it there a way we can add transition to the javascript during moving to the next pages?

Comment: @i_user Was not certain of expected results, after re-reading OP; added alternative plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/tunX9CjEqNEZWxoxXU1b

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98081/discussion-between-i-user-and-guest271314).